# Adding same thing to two different vectors results in different results

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following for loop that is nest inside another for loop.
I am adding to the indices vector but when I print the contents they are different.

```
for(unsigned int j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j = j + 3) {
                //setting indices
                 indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);

                std::cout << "Realindices: " << face.mIndices[j] << " "
                std::cout << "insideindices: " <<indices[j]<< " ";

                if (j + 1 < face.mNumIndices) {
                    indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j + 1]);
                std::cout << "Realindices: " << face.mIndices[j + 1] << " ";
                std::cout << "insideindices: " << indices[j + 1] << " ";
                }
                if (j + 2 < face.mNumIndices) {
                    indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j + 2]);

                 std::cout << "Realindices: " << face.mIndices[j + 2] << " ";
                std::cout << "insideindices: " << indices[j + 2] << " ";

             }
```

Here is the terminal output:

```
Realindices: 8293 insideindices: 1 Realindices: 8294 insideindices: 2 
Realindices: 8295 insideindices: 0 Realindices: 8296 insideindices: 1 
Realindices: 8297 insideindices: 2 Realindices: 8298 insideindices: 0 
Realindices: 8299 insideindices: 1 Realindices: 8300 insideindices: 2 
Realindices: 8301 insideindices: 0 Realindices: 8302 insideindices: 1 
Realindices: 8303 insideindices: 2 Realindices: 8304 insideindices: 0 
Realindices: 8305 insideindices: 1 Realindices: 8306 insideindices: 2 
Realindices: 8307 insideindices: 0 Realindices: 8308 insideindices: 1 
Realindices: 8309 insideindices: 2 Realindices: 8310 insideindices: 0 
Realindices: 8311 insideindices: 1 Realindices: 8312 insideindices: 2 
Realindices: 8313 insideindices: 0 Realindices: 8314 insideindices: 1
```

(snippit of total output)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps adding some newlines in the output (to see when the loops end), and showing what's in the outer loop?

Comment: My guess would be, `indices` is not empty coming into the loop. `indices.push_back(face.mIndices[0])` takes 0th element from `face.mIndices`, and puts it at an index other than 0 in `indices`. The element you print next is not the element you've just added. Make it `std::cout << "insideindices: " <<indices.back()`, so you actually print the last element added.